# bash: function with history -d won't remove history entry

Tags: linux, bash, command-history

After reading some posts, could not figure out how comes `history -d 1` in a function does not delete the entry.

The function below goes directly to the command line:

```bash
function test () {
  echo "HISTFILE: '${HISTFILE}'"
  history -d 1
}
```

Then we run:

```
history -c
echo "to remove"
history
    1  echo "to remove"
    2  history
echo $(test)
HISTFILE: '/home/user/.bash_history'
history
    1  echo "to remove"
    2  history
    3  echo $(test)
    4  history
```

Any ideas on how comes it does not remove the first entry of the history?

Comment: Why are you running your function in a command substitution as the argument of `echo`? You don't need to echo its output (it does this just fin by itself already), and the command substitution creates a subshell.

Comment: thanks @Kusalananda... that did it... just `test` on the command line worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function (which, by the way, overloads the name of a standard utility, so you should probably change that) is being run within a command substitution, a separate subshell.

Within the subshell, it removes the first history entry.  It does not affect the history of the invoking shell, though.

First, rename the function to something other than `test` (this does not fix the error, but `test` is a standard utility already), then stop using `echo $(some-command)` to output the output of a command or function.  It's an anti-pattern with several issues.  Just use the function's name directly; it is already doing its own output.

Apart from `echo` and the command substitution being unnecessary, the `echo` may change the command output if the output contains backslashes.  The unquoted command substitution also causes the shell to split the command output on spaces, tabs, and newlines (any character in `$IFS`), and it would apply filename globbing to the split-up words. The `echo` utility would then output all generated words with spaces between them on a single line.

Related:

- [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694)
- [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803) (related to the issues with `echo`, but I'm definitely not saying that you should use `printf` in this instance!)